# p-summable sequence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let Y be a closed linear subspace of X and suppose that Y does not have copy of l1 .Does each weakly p-summable sequence in X/Y has a subsequence that's the image of  a weakly p-summable sequence in X under the natural quotient map?

Comment: What copy are you excluding? Could you make that more precise? What exactly do you mean by weakly $p$-summable?

Comment: @anton Here is my interpretation. (1) Y does not have any closed linear subspace that is TVS isomorphic to $\ell^1$ (2) a sequence $(v_n)_{n\geq 1}$ in a Banach space $E$ should be weakly p-summable if for all $\psi\in E^*$ the sequence $(\psi(v_n))_{n\geq 1}$ belongs to $\ell^p$.

Answer (score 4):

A sequence $(x_n)$ is weakly $p$ summable if the mapping $e_n\mapsto x_n$ extends to a bounded linear operator from $\ell_{p^*}$ into $X$.  IMO, this is the right way to look at weakly $p$ summable sequences.  So your question asks whether you can lift a certain linear operator into $X/Y$ back into $X$  through the quotient map.  Take $X=L_r$ with $2<r<\infty$. Then $\ell_{p^*}$ is a quotient of $L_r$ if $r^*<p<2$, so you are asking for  the identity on $\ell_{p^*}$ to lift to $L_r$ through the quotient map. This would force $\ell_{p^*}$ to embed isomorphically into $L_r$, which it does not.